# JDK log rotation

Tags: java, logging, hazelcast, java-6

I am using JDK logging and I am trying to set log-rotation of log based on size.The configuration file logging.properties is set as shown below :

```
# Specify the handlers to create in the root logger
# (all loggers are children of the root logger)
# The following creates two handlers
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
#handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
#handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler

# Set the default logging level for the root logger
.level = INFO

# Set the default logging level for new ConsoleHandler instances
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO

# Set the default logging level for new FileHandler instances, INFO, FINEST...
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = INFO

# Set the default formatter for new ConsoleHandler instances
#java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = com.hazelcast.impl.LogFormatter
#java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = com.hazelcast.impl.LogFormatter
#java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = ./hazelcast%u.log

# Set the default logging level for the logger named com.hazelcast
com.hazelcast.level = INFO

# Limiting size of output file in bytes: 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=1024

# Number of output files to cycle through, by appending an 
# integer to the base file name: 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=10
```

I see the log been written into file but I dont see any effect on log-rotation based on size.I am using hazelcast API which implements the logger and I am trying to configure the properties through file.Help would be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Rajeev

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Hazelcast Logging Configuration](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/logging.html) the default logging framework is JDK logging.  So all of the configuration is setup in the logging.properties.

The size of the log file has to exceed the limit (1024) before the rotation.  You have **not** set a pattern in your logging properties so the FileHandler will default to your home folder starting with 'java0.log.0'.

The following code is self-contained conversion of your logging properties that does not require any system properties to be set on launch.

```
    public class JdkLogRotation {

        private static final String LOGGER_NAME = "com.hazelcast";
        private static final int LIMIT = 1024;
        private static final int COUNT = 10;
        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME);

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Properties props = create();
            read(LogManager.getLogManager(), props);
            String msg = message();
            for (int i = 0; i <= COUNT; ++i) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, msg);
            }

            /*
            try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),
                            "jdklogrotation.properties"))) {
                props.store(out, "JDK log rotation");
                out.flush();
            }*/
        }

        private static String message() {
            char[] c = new char[LIMIT + 1];
            Arrays.fill(c, 'A');
            return String.valueOf(c);
        }

        private static Properties create() {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("handlers", "java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler");
            props.setProperty(".level", "INFO");
            props.setProperty("java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level", "INFO");
            props.setProperty("java.util.logging.FileHandler.level", "INFO");
            props.setProperty("java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit", String.valueOf(LIMIT));
            props.setProperty("java.util.logging.FileHandler.count", "10");
            props.setProperty(LOGGER_NAME + ".level", "INFO");
            return props;
        }

        private static void read(LogManager manager, Properties props) throws IOException {
            final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(512);
            props.store(out, "No comment");
            manager.readConfiguration(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
        }
    }
```

The following log file names are created in your user home folder:

```
java0.log.0
java0.log.1
java0.log.2
java0.log.3
java0.log.4
java0.log.5
java0.log.6
java0.log.7
java0.log.8
java0.log.9
```

Assuming your logging.properties is loaded and nothing has reset your LogManager you should expect to see the same output.

Comment: I am using hazelcast api as part of my code.I guess the api does the file handling part because I find that the log (cdc.log) is getting saved under a particular path .My aim is to control these log outputs.I see from hazelcast api docs on setting different log levels which i am able to successfully using the logging.properties file but however when it comes  to setting max file size and rotation of log I am unable to do so and yes I checked the log size exceeds the one set in property file.So basically somethingabout the property file is wrong.

Comment: The "cdc.log" is not a file pattern that you specified in your logging properties.  Set a FileHandler.pattern using an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast logging (its more of a general logging problem) sometimes can be a big PITA.

First make sure you have logging configured through a system property, don't rely on the properties inside of the hazelcast.xml file because it could be that a logger is triggered before this file is loaded and then things get funky.

So something like -Dhazelcast.logging.type=jdk.

And remove the hazelcast.logging.type if you have that in your hazelcast.xml file.

Second step: Do you see hazelcast.log being created? Just to be sure that your log configuration is picked up, give it a completly different name just to be totally sure that it got picked up, e.g. monty-python.log. If you don't see this file appearing, then you know your log file isn't picked up.

If this file is picked up; then I would try to figure out why your config doesn't work. I have wasted too much time on configuration issues with logging that were not actually related to the actual configuration file.